# Import Python Module into C++ raises segmentation fault

Tags: c++, python-3.x, interpreter, gil

I am trying to embed a Python module into a C++ program to be imported into another C++ software for scientific research. The issue is that I am having a hard time running the C++ program without having any segmentation faults, as importing pyatomdb (which is custom module) raises unfamiliar issues with what appears to be scipy. Some explanations for the unconventional code: the import_array() function is called in initPython() instead of the constructor, as doing so otherwise yields this error:

```
pp: In constructor ‘ApecCalc::ApecCalc()’:
/home/avalderr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1553:151: error: returning a value from a constructor
 y() < 0) {PyErr_Print(); PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ImportError, "numpy.core.multiarray failed to import"); return NULL;
```

Additionally, the software will ignore the main function (I currently have it in the sample code for testing), and will only read from pyApecInfo- hence creating the class object in that function and passing parameters into it.

wrapper.cpp

```
#include <python3.9/Python.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "xsTypes.h"


using namespace std;

class ApecCalc {
public:
  ApecCalc() { Py_Initialize(); initPython();}

  //RealArray is defined as an std::valarray<Real>, while Real is defined as a double in xsTypes.h
  void caller(const RealArray& energy, const RealArray& params, int spectrum, RealArray& flux, RealArray& fluxvariance, const string& initString) {

 PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
 PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\".\")");

 //import the apec_xspec.py module 
 pyModule = PyImport_ImportModule("apec_xspec");
 if (!pyModule) {
   PyErr_Print();
   std::cerr << "Failed to import apec_xspec  module\n";
   return;
 }

 PyObject* pyapecFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pyModule, "pyapec");
 if (!pyapecFunc || !PyCallable_Check(pyapecFunc)) {
   Py_XDECREF(pyapecFunc);
   Py_DECREF(pyModule);
   std::cerr << "pyapec function not found or not callable\n";
   return;
 }

 //create a new Python list with the same size as the RealArray vectors

 PyObject* pyEngs = PyList_New(energy.size());
 PyObject* pyParams = PyList_New(params.size());
 PyObject* pyFlux = PyList_New(flux.size());


 //loop through each list and set each element with the corresponding value as its vector
 for (size_t i = 0; i < energy.size(); ++i) {
   PyList_SetItem(pyEngs, i, PyFloat_FromDouble(energy[i]));
 }

 for (size_t i = 0; i < params.size(); ++i) {
   PyList_SetItem(pyParams, i, PyFloat_FromDouble(params[i]));
 }

 for (size_t i = 0; i < flux.size(); ++i) {
   PyList_SetItem(pyFlux, i, PyFloat_FromDouble(flux[i]));

 }

 //create a new typle object to pass the arguments to pyapecFunc
 PyObject* pyArgs = PyTuple_New(3);
 PyTuple_SetItem(pyArgs, 0, pyEngs);
 PyTuple_SetItem(pyArgs, 1, pyParams);
 PyTuple_SetItem(pyArgs, 2, pyFlux);

 //call pyapecFunc in apec_xspec with the arguments contained in the python tuple pyArgs, return the result in pyResult
 PyObject* pyResult = PyObject_CallObject(pyapecFunc, pyArgs);
 if (!pyResult) {
   PyErr_Print();  // Print Python error information
   Py_XDECREF(pyapecFunc);
   Py_DECREF(pyModule);
   Py_DECREF(pyArgs);
   std::cerr << "Error occurred during pyapec function call\n";
   return;
 }

 for (size_t i = 0; i < flux.size(); ++i) {
   flux[i] = PyFloat_AsDouble(PyList_GetItem(pyFlux, i));
 }
 Py_DECREF(pyResult);
 Py_DECREF(pyapecFunc);
 Py_DECREF(pyModule);
 Py_DECREF(pyArgs);
 Py_Finalize();
}


   ~ApecCalc() { Py_Finalize(); }
 
private:
  bool initPython() {
    
    import_array();
    if (PyErr_Occurred()) {
      PyErr_Print();
      PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ImportError, "Failed to import numpy.core.multiarray");
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  PyObject* pyModule = nullptr;
  PyObject* pyapecFunc = nullptr;
};


extern"C" void pyApecInfo(const RealArray& energy, const RealArray& params, int spectrum, RealArray& flux, RealArray& fluxvariance, const string& initString) {
  ApecCalc calc;
  calc.caller(energy,params,spectrum,flux,fluxvariance,initString);

}


int main() {
  
    RealArray energy = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
    RealArray params = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    RealArray flux(3);
    RealArray fluxvariance(3);

    pyApecInfo(energy, params, 3, flux, fluxvariance, "eek");
    
    return 0;
}
```

apec_xspec.py

```
import numpy
import pyatomdb

#initialize CX object
cie = pyatomdb.spectrum.CIESession()

def pyapec(engs, params, flux):

    # This is the call that will return everything. So set everything!
    ebins = numpy.array(engs)

    elements = []
    for i in range(1, 31):
        elements.append(i)

    eloffset = 0  # Assign a default value to eloffset
    abund = None  # Assign a default value to abund

    if len(params) == 4:
        # apec model
        abund = numpy.array(params[1])
        elements = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
                    16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
        eloffset = 2
    elif len(params) == 17:
        # apec model
        elements = [1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 16, 18, 20, 26, 28]
        abund = params[1:15]
        eloffset = 15
    elif len(params) == 33:
        # apec model
        elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
                    16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
        abund = params[1:31]
        eloffset = 31

    # Check if abund is still None
    if abund is None:
        raise ValueError("Invalid params")

    # get redshift
    redshift = float(params[eloffset + 0])

    # set energy bins, accounting for redshift
    cie.set_response(ebins * (1.0 + redshift), raw=True)

    # set abundance vector
    cie.set_abund(elements, abund)
    cie.set_eebrems(False)

    # get the spectrum
    spec = cie.return_spectrum(params[0], log_interp=False)

    # return the flux.
    flux[:] = spec * 1e14
```

The line used to compile the code:
`g++ -g -I/home/avalderr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 wrapper.cpp -L/usr/lib/python3.9/config-3/-3.9-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.9 -o output`

Valgrind error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/scratch1/avalderr/pyspectrum3/./apec_xspec.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pyatomdb
  File "/home/avalderr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyatomdb/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .atomdb import *
  File "/home/avalderr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyatomdb/atomdb.py", line 25, in <module>
    from scipy import stats, integrate
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1055, in _handle_fromlist
  File "/home/avalderr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/__init__.py", line 200, in __getattr__
    return _importlib.import_module(f'scipy.{name}')
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/avalderr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/stats/__init__.py", line 485, in <module>
    from ._stats_py import *
  File "/home/avalderr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/stats/_stats_py.py", line 46, in <module>
    from . import distributions
  File "/home/avalderr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/stats/distributions.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import _continuous_distns
  File "/home/avalderr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py", line 32, in <module>
    import scipy.stats._boost as _boost
  File "/home/avalderr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/stats/_boost/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scipy.stats._boost.beta_ufunc import (
SystemError: initialization of beta_ufunc raised unreported exception
Failed to import apec_xspec  module
```

Having `PyRun_SimpleString("import scipy.stats")` in the constructor reduces the number of segmentation fault errors, but these are  the ones I am still facing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/avalderr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/stats/__init__.py", line 485, in <module>
    from ._stats_py import *
  File "/home/avalderr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/stats/_stats_py.py", line 46, in <module>
    from . import distributions
  File "/home/avalderr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/stats/distributions.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import _continuous_distns
  File "/home/avalderr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py", line 32, in <module>
    import scipy.stats._boost as _boost
  File "/home/avalderr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/stats/_boost/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scipy.stats._boost.beta_ufunc import (
SystemError: initialization of beta_ufunc raised unreported exception
```

I've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling my python system and numpy. Any and all help would be appreciated, along with ways to develop more efficient code in this process as I am still relatively new to embedding Python in C++!